# Can someone explain this tweet about activated fusion reactor materials?

Tags: radioactivity, fusion

This tweet is a joke, I assume: https://twitter.com/scipython3/status/1422923046113927170 but I don't understand why it would be a good thing to make a reactor out of a material that becomes low-level radioactive waste after only 10 years. Wouldn't it be better to use a material that takes a long time to become activated?

[image]

Comment: If it rapidly decays to low level, then you don't care how hot it got in the first place. You can run it for decades and not worry that the site becomes a thousand year problem. Consider that it may hit steady state, cooling as fast as you are radiating it.

Comment: (But, yes, Au is not exactly a structural material)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding the chart.  It's not that it takes gold 1-10 years to become activated; it's that once gold has been exposed to pulsed operation of the reactor for five years, it takes 1-10 years for it to *return* to LLW.

Comment: Aha! Now I understand – thank you. So every other stable element is highly activated within 5 years of operation and then has to decay away before it can be safely handled? Nuclear fusion energy doesn't sound as clean as it's been claimed...